# How do I beat level 10 ("Climbing") in Blocks That Matter?

Tags: blocks-that-matter

Simply put, I'm stuck on this one. I can't figure out how to leap from left to right over that big gap at the bottom of the level. I don't have enough blocks to place any tetrominoes to use as a platform, since I can't break the smooth stone blocks near the chest or the falling gravel.

[image: Level 10 map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold the drill button as you jump. That will let you jump farther distances.

[image]

Comment: Don't ask me how to get the chest though. I have no idea.